# How to update/remove managed picklist dependencies through metadata api

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api

I am trying to use the metadata api to remove a picklist dependency on a managed picklist field.  As an admin I am able to do this manually.  I want to be able to automate this process.  My metadata api code works when the picklist is not a managed component.  Help?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm
https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

```
public static PageReference breakDependency()
{
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    MetadataService.CustomField customField = (MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata(
        'CustomField', new String[] { 'Account.County__c' }
    ).getRecords()[0];

    metadataservice.Picklist pt = new metadataservice.Picklist();
    pt.sorted= false;
    //pt.controllingField = '';  no define = no controlling field.
    metadataservice.PicklistValue two = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
    two.fullName= 'Non NY Stuffs';
    two.default_x=false;
    pt.picklistValues = new list<metadataservice.PicklistValue>{two};
    customField.picklist = pt ;

    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
    handleSaveResults(results[0]);
    return null;  
}
```